# Interacting with a RJ11 "phone" / Hardware

Tags: gpio, hardware

I'd like to be able to interract with a piece of hardware which is able to be controlled by a standard phone line (and provide vocal metrics, ...)

Let me stress that it is not a modem, nor has it modem capabilities. I'm playing with plain old DTMF and pre-recorded audio messages.

What I want to achieve is :

- Intercept phone calls triggerd by the device
- Trigger a phone call to the device

And in both case being able to detect/send DTMF and record audio messages on the PI.

It has it's own power source so I suppose it won't need much of the power provided by a normal phone line. Thus I hope it will work with GPIO power...

Do you have any ideas on how to achieve this ?

Comment: Do you want the Pi to act like a telephone and be able to "call" and "answer calls from" this device, or do you want to "tap" the line it's connected to and listen in?

Comment: Using an old modem with a DTMF decoder built in is actually exactly what you want.  3COM used to have a modem with every feature you need, it had a built in DTMF decoder and could also digitally record rec'd over the phone line.

Comment: @TomG I want it to act like a telephone. I don't want to tap on it. One reason is the fact that there is no real phone line availiable.

Comment: @Tyson I wasn't able to find a suitable modem : I've found out about http://linux.die.net/man/8/vgetty but all voice-modems I found where PCI cards which doesn't help when you have a PI

Comment: I was heading down the path of using Asterisk with a USB device to connect to the phone line, but there don't seem to be many options at the low end.

Comment: While not *explicitly* off-topic here, as you are attempting to do this on the Raspberry Pi, this question might fit better on [so]. That's a programming-specific site, whereas this site is Raspberry Pi-specific. We would love to help you, but I believe you will get better and more answers on Stack Overflow. Another viable option is [unix.se], but I would attempt [so] first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many solutions to this hardware selection problem.

I would suggest this specific google search term `RS232 modem voice DTMF`.

Using that search term I saw a number of choices, including [this one](http://www.radi.com/modular41.htm) that seems to have the additional advantage of operating on 5V.

While you may not think that a "MOdulator DEModulator" (i.e. MODEM) is what you want, it is.  You just don't want the computer to computer over telephone line communication convention.  However you certainly do what to modulate and demodulate analog to digital, which is what a modem does.

For interface to the pi, you might want to use [this](http://www.davidhunt.ie/add-a-9-pin-serial-port-to-your-raspberry-pi-in-10-minutes/) or something like it.